# How to insert a duplicate value in primary key column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has primary key on first column, but when I see the data available of this table, I find that records are repeated include primary key data. I want to know how can it be possible? Does primary column has repeated data in SQL Server 2008?

[image]

```
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO

        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO

        SET ANSI_PADDING ON
        GO

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl](
            [ProcedureId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [ProcedureName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
            [VersionNo] [char](5) NULL,
            [PublishDate] [datetime] NULL,
            [PublishUser] [varchar](50) NULL,

            [SpecialtyId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [ProcedureNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
            [PowerpointName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
            [Duration] [int] NOT NULL,

            [LanguageId] [int] NOT NULL,

            [TierId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
            [PrintPdf] [bit] NULL,
            [PresentationModeId] [tinyint] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [pk_DemoTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [ProcedureId] ASC,
            [LanguageId] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO

        SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([PresentationModeId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[DemoTbl] ([PresentationModeId])
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoTbl_Specialty] FOREIGN KEY([SpecialtyId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Specialty] ([SpecialtyId])
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoTbl_Specialty]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoTbl_TierMaster] FOREIGN KEY([TierId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[TierMaster] ([TierId])
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoTbl_TierMaster]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DemoTbl_CreationDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreationDate]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DemoTbl_ModifiedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedDate]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DemoTbl_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsActive]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DemoTbl_LanguageId]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [LanguageId]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DemoTbl_ManageContent]  DEFAULT ('false') FOR [ManageContent]
        GO

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Procedure__Print__1B14C01D]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [PrintPdf]
        GO
```

Comment: Could this be a composite primary key?  Your image simply does not look possible for the same table in the same database.

Comment: A Primary key is unique by definition. Are you sure the results in the image are the results of a single select on a single table?

Comment: Show us the create table statement. (And also alter table, if any.)

Comment: can you please post the table create sql script. I would like to see if it is exactly what constraints are present for that table

Comment: Run a SQL: SELECT Count(Pk) as MyCount FROM myTable Group By Pk Having Count(Pk) > 1. If you get results, check if your Primary key is really a primary key. If so, you server is in trouble... If not, the problem is with your data displayer

Comment: yes it's composite key

Comment: Then do you still have a question?

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not possible in SQL Server to insert records that have duplicate values in the Primary Key.

Comment: I would also add that is not possible in any of the relational database engines by defenition.

Comment: Agreed - and to me, the theory that the ProedureId column is _not_ acutally a primary key ( perhaps a key, but not the primary key) seems the most parsimonious.  A CREATE TABLE example would show that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have more than one row in the same table with the same primary key (PK).

If you are doing a SELECT and getting more than one row with the same PK could be because:

1. That table actually does not have a PK, maybe it was not properly created. You can check this by doing the following (it should return the PK column(s)):

   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'TableName' AND COLUMN_KEY='PRI';
2. The SELECT statement is not correct. Maybe you are selecting from two or more tables and you are not relating them correctly.

To clarify, you can do the following:
1- Create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer` (
   `id` int(4),
   `name` varchar(20),
   `surname` varchar(40),
   `phone` int(9),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now you have a new table for storing customers identified by an ID.
2- Let's add some customers:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(111, 'John', 'White', 123456789),
    (222, 'Bianca', 'Williams', 987654321),
    (333, 'Mikel', 'Peterson', 421345642),
    (444, 'Jolene', 'Gomez', 948113552);
```

3- If you try to insert a customer with an existing PK (id) you will get an error:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (222, 'Paul', 'Brown', 123412345);
```

4- In order to check the final table, you can do the following select:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to have duplicate primary keys if the `primary key constraint` has been set to `True`.

Further to prevent duplicate primary keys set the `Identity Specification` to `True`

Answer (score 0):

If this table is an intermediate table in a many to many connection the original columns are foreign keys and able to accept many instances of the same prodId(the whole point of the exercise). If someone then slams a PK on that column then no more duplicates can be added but if you query it the table will still return the original stuff in this guys screenshot.

This scenario can be seen in the Northwind sample database between Products and orders (OrderDetails table has composite PK on OrderID, ProdID but still shows duplicates of both). The PK was added afterwards, after data had been added.

The intermediate table is a link between the Many-to-Many tables and in general doesn't need a PK. Normalization 101.

Answer (score 0):

For PK Constraint it create a Unique Index (Clustered / non Clustered ) on defined PK. If we disable indexes before loading that include PK Unique Index as well than we can insert duplicate PK in the column because the PK constraint is disabled. So while disabling Indexes please avoid PK index not be disable "is_primary_key=0 to disable all other indexes"

Comment: Yes, I also heard same. can you add simple example

Answer (score -1):

Tested -> it's possible if we create a primary key with nonclustered index. If we disable this index we will be able to insert duplicated record then. But - it won't be possible to enable (rebuild) the index back with duplicated values on primary key

Comment: Welcome here. Kindly check FAQs before posting an answer to make them helpful and also getting upvotes.